# SQL query is running, but stopped producing incremental results

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have the below query running in SQL Server.  In a nutshell, I have 3 somewhat identical queries "unioned".  When I start the query, it runs and produces incremental results in the Results pane.  But, once it reaches 264,619 records (first 5 minutes), it just stops producing results, yet the query is running and has been running for 30 minutes.  Any ideas why this is happening?  I understand the query below is kind of long/semi-complex, so my apologies, I couldn't make it any simpler (I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in a direction that I would be able to make the query below a little simpler).  Below the query is a screenshot of the results pane.  I'm wondering if the query is deadlocked somewhere or running into an infinite loop/etc.:

```
  select
    Q1.[Transaction Identifier],
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as 'Transaction Sequence Number',
    Q1.HL_Acct_ID,
    Q1.AcctNumber,
    Q1.AcctType,
    Q1.AcctSource,
    Q1.DUNS_NBR,
    Q1.DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID,
    Q1.CellCode,
    Q1.OfferCode,
    Q1.ResponseType,
    Q1.ResponseDate,
    Q1.ResponseQuantity,
    Q1.ResponseValue,
    Q1.ResponseChannel,
    Q1.[Cookie ID],
    Q1.[IP Address],
    Q1.[Device ID],
    Q1.[CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
    Q1.[CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
    Q1.[CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
    Q1.[CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
    Q1.[CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
    from
    (
      select
        'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
        s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
        null as [AcctNumber],
        null as [AcctType],
        null as [AcctSource],
        null as [DUNS_NBR],
        null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
        s.CELLCODE as [CellCode],
        case
          when c.URL is not null then c.URL
          else '-1'
        end as [OfferCode],
        case
          when c.EventDate is not null then 'Click'
          when c.EventDate is null then
          case
            when sub.status = 'unsubscribed' then 'Unsubscribe'
            when sub.status = 'bounced' then 'Bounce'
            when sub.status = 'held' then 'Bounce'
          end
        end as [ResponseType],
        convert(varchar, c.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
        null as [ResponseQuantity],
        null as [ResponseValue],
        'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
        null as [Cookie ID],
        null as [IP address],
        null as [Device ID],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
        from C1111111.[151222_Hostess Ensemble] s with (nolock)
        inner join C1111111._subscribers sub with (nolock) on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
        left join C1111111._click c with (nolock) on c.JobID in
        (
          select j.fkJobId from tblJobs_Lists j with (nolock)
          inner join customobject c with (nolock) on j.customobjectid = c.customobjectid
          where c.memberid = 1111111
          and c.customobjectname like '151222_Hostess Ensemble'
        )
        and c.SubscriberKey = s.Email
      where c.EventDate is not null or (c.EventDate is null and (sub.status in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held'))) and c.isunique = 1

      union all

      select
        'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
        s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
        null as [AcctNumber],
        null as [AcctType],
        null as [AcctSource],
        null as [DUNS_NBR],
        null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
        s.CELLCODE as [CellCode],
        '-1' as [OfferCode],
        case
          when o.EventDate is not null then 'Message Open'
          when o.EventDate is null then
          case
            when sub.status = 'unsubscribed' then 'Unsubscribe'
            when sub.status = 'bounced' then 'Bounce'
            when sub.status = 'held' then 'Bounce'
          end
        end as [ResponseType],
        convert(varchar, o.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
        null as [ResponseQuantity],
        null as [ResponseValue],
        'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
        null as [Cookie ID],
        null as [IP address],
        null as [Device ID],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
        from C1111111.[151222_Hostess Ensemble] s with (nolock)
        inner join C1111111._subscribers sub with (nolock) on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
        left join C1111111._open o with (nolock) on o.JobID in
        (
          select j.fkJobId from tblJobs_Lists j with (nolock)
          inner join customobject c with (nolock) on j.customobjectid = c.customobjectid
          where c.memberid = 1111111
          and c.customobjectname like '151222_Hostess Ensemble'
        )
        and o.SubscriberKey = s.Email
      where o.EventDate is not null or (o.EventDate is null and (sub.status in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held'))) and o.isunique = 1

      UNION ALL

      select
        'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
        s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
        null as [AcctNumber],
        null as [AcctType],
        null as [AcctSource],
        null as [DUNS_NBR],
        null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
        s.CELLCODE as [CellCode],
        '-1' as [OfferCode],
        null as [ResponseType],
        convert(varchar, o.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
        null as [ResponseQuantity],
        null as [ResponseValue],
        'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
        null as [Cookie ID],
        null as [IP address],
        null as [Device ID],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
        from C1111111.[151222_Hostess Ensemble] s with (nolock)
        inner join C1111111._subscribers sub with (nolock) on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
        left join C1111111._open o with (nolock) on o.JobID in
        (
          select j.fkJobId from tblJobs_Lists j with (nolock)
          inner join customobject c with (nolock) on j.customobjectid = c.customobjectid
          where c.memberid = 1111111
          and c.customobjectname like '151222_Hostess Ensemble'
        )
        left join C1111111._click cl with (nolock) on o.JobID in
        (
          select j.fkJobId from tblJobs_Lists j with (nolock)
          inner join customobject c with (nolock) on j.customobjectid = c.customobjectid
          where c.memberid = 1111111
          and c.customobjectname like '151222_Hostess Ensemble'
        )
        and cl.SubscriberKey = s.Email
      where cl.EventDate is null and o.EventDate is null and sub.status not in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held')) as Q1
```

[image]

Comment: The reason might be visible in the query plan you get for the above query, A guess from me would be that the first or even the second and the first parts can return the rows as they come out of the tables but the last part has a sort or some other kind of blocking operator that needs to consume all rows from the table(s) before it can pass them on to the parent operator.

Comment: I would try running each of the 3 parts separately. Maybe the first one takes 5 minutes to run, but the second one takes an hour?

Comment: When I see a sub-select in a join I always evaluate if I can make it a join and not an `in` - often it runs faster that way

Comment: Why put all the `null as [AcctNumber],
        null as [AcctType],
        null as [AcctSource],
        null as [DUNS_NBR],
        null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],` etc. in the union all?

Comment: You really need to run these individually.  Especially the last one.  The Join conditions to `_open` and `_click` look suspicion to me, they are NOT the same as the conditions used in the earlier two, and may be causing a full join to be occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Without the table definitions I can't verify that this is correct, but this would be my take at a simplification of the above, with an assumption about two fixes in the join conditions:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
WITH JobIDs AS
(
    select j.fkJobId from tblJobs_Lists j
    inner join customobject c on j.customobjectid = c.customobjectid
    where c.memberid = 1111111
    and c.customobjectname = '151222_Hostess Ensemble'
)
select
        'ACCT PROMORESP' as 'Transaction Identifier',
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as 'Transaction Sequence Number',
    s.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_Acct_ID',
        null as [AcctNumber],
        null as [AcctType],
        null as [AcctSource],
        null as [DUNS_NBR],
        null as [DBPLCR_CONTACT_ID],
    s.CELLCODE as [CellCode],
    X.OfferCode,
    X.ResponseType,
    convert(varchar, X.EventDate, 112) as [ResponseDate],
        null as [ResponseQuantity],
        null as [ResponseValue],
        'Email' as [ResponseChannel],
        null as [Cookie ID],
        null as [IP address],
        null as [Device ID],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_01],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_02],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_03],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_04],
        null as [CUSTOM_TEXT_05]
    from 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.HL_ACCT_ID,
            s.CELLCODE,
            s.Email,
            case sub.status
                when 'unsubscribed' then 'Unsubscribe'
                when 'bounced' then 'Bounce'
                when 'held' then 'Bounce'
            end as [ResponseType],
            sub.status
        from C1111111.[151222_Hostess Ensemble] s
        inner join C1111111._subscribers sub on sub.SubscriberKey = s.Email
    ) as s 

    left join C1111111._open o on o.JobID in (select fkJobId from JobIDs)
    -- DON'T YOU NEED A "and o.SubscriberKey = s.Email" HERE?
    and o.SubscriberKey = s.Email

    left join C1111111._click cl on cl.JobID in (select fkJobId from JobIDs)
    -- LOOK ABOVE, was "o.JobID", **REALLY**
    and cl.SubscriberKey = s.Email

    cross apply (
        select 
            '-1' as [OfferCode],
            case
                when o.EventDate is not null then 'Message Open'
                else s.[ResponseType]
            end as [ResponseType],
            o.EventDate         
        where o.EventDate is not null or (o.EventDate is null and (s.status in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held'))) and o.isunique = 1
    UNION ALL 
        select
            isnull(cl.URL,'-1') as [OfferCode],
            case 
                when c.EventDate is not null then 'Click'
                else s.[ResponseType]
            end as [ResponseType],
            cl.EventDate
        where cl.EventDate is not null or (cl.EventDate is null and (s.status in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held'))) and cl.isunique = 1
    union all
        select 
            '-1' as [OfferCode],
            NULL AS [ResponseType],
            null as EventDate
        where cl.EventDate is null and o.EventDate is null and s.status not in ('unsubscribed','bounced','held')
    ) AS X
```